# Application is being closed automatically after iPad locked

Tags: ios, xcode

I have enabled Background Fetch from capabilities.

[image: Please find the snapshot]

Please give me solution that once user open the application, it should not closed automatically.

Comment: what do you mean by application closed?

Comment: And for whatever you mean by closed (see @Basheer comment), present evidence that the app has entered the unwanted state.

Comment: Application is closed mean- Suppose we launched the application, it is working fine till that time till user interaction, when user keep device for some time device gets locked. When user unlock device again, application didn't enter in background state. It is closed. User need to re-launch the application. Application start from initial VC not from that screen, where user left.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `UIBackgroundModes` does not make you app keep running in background.

> Each of the preceding modes lets the system know that your app should be woken up or launched at appropriate times to respond to relevant events. For example, an app that begins playing music and then moves to the background still needs execution time to fill the audio output buffers. Enabling the Audio mode tells the system frameworks that they should continue to make the necessary callbacks to the app at appropriate intervals. If the app does not select this mode, any audio being played or recorded by the app stops when the app moves to the background.

You will have to either have a task running or callbackHandlers to respond when OS send any signal from the background task as shown in example from Apple

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Please follow [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for more details.